# Using hvlines in NiceTabularX causes the last column to add tabcolsep

Tags: geometry, nicematrix

I think this is a bug in `nicematrix`. Is it possible to patch the package to get the desired result? (i.e., the letter l in Fadeel should align with text margin)

[image: 1]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\NiceMatrixOptions{hvlines}

\begin{document}

\noindent%
\begin{NiceTabularX}{\linewidth}{@{}p[l]{1.1cm} X[1, t, r] r@{}}[cell-space-limits=1.1961pt]
    
    Basmah & & Fadeel
    \\
    
\end{NiceTabularX}

\end{document}
```

Comment: if you think it is a bug (and imho you are right) then report it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(I'm the author of the package `nicematrix`).

I have uploaded on CTAN a new version of `nicematrix` (v 6.13f of 2023-02-05) which solves that bug.

Comment: Great package and responses to reports and feedback